# PostGis ST_ConcaveHull Zero Longitude Error

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Running the following query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-0.211393 51.606972, -0.237981 51.624109, -0.237982 51.624104)',4326),0.99))
```

returns a soft error:

```
POLYGON((-0 0,-0 0,-0 0,-0 0))
```

However if my longitudinal coordinates are bumped up (or down) out of the -0.999..0.999 range then it works:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-1.211393 51.606972, -1.237981 51.624109, -1.237982 51.624104)',4326),0.99))
```

gives

```
POLYGON((-1.211393 51.606972,-1.237982 51.624104,-1.237981 51.624109,-1.211393 51.606972))
```

What is going on here?!

Comment: works fine with PostGIS 2.3.2 -> `POLYGON((-0.211393 51.606972,-0.237982 51.624104,-0.237981 51.624109,-0.211393 51.606972))`

Comment: I can confirm it's broke on Ubuntu 17.04 `POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797"`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a [bug #1973](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1973) fixed in PostGIS 2.1.3, from the [Changelog](https://postgis.net/docs/release_notes.html)

> #1973, st_concavehull() returns sometimes empty geometry collection Fix from gde

Comment: Interesting - thanks - I'm using PostGIS 2.2.2 r14797 looks like this bug has crept back in...

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a recurring problem, we created a work-around using ST_Translate. So instead of doing:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-0.211393 51.606972, -0.237981 51.624109, -0.237982 51.624104)',4326),0.99))
```

we're using ST_Translate twice - once to translate it 360 degrees east (before the concavehull calculation), and then translate the result 360 degrees west again - so:

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Translate(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Translate(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-0.211393 51.606972, -0.237981 51.624109, -0.237982 51.624104)',4326),360,0,0),0.99),-360,0,0))
```

The translations are fast so there should be no major performance impact.

Hope that helps someone else!